# How does sp.record arrange data into pairs?

Tags: michelson, smartpy

For example if I have the following code:

```
sp.record(one = one, two = two, three = three, four = four, five = five)
```

Would the format of the result be

`pair(one pair(two pair(three pair(four five))))`
or
`pair( pair(one two) pair(three pair(four five))`
or something else?

What is the rule behind the ordering? And is there a quick way to view it in SmartPy? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is called a *layout* in SmartPy.

Layouts are attached to types and can be determined when you define a `sp.TRecord` (you can look at templates FA2 and FA1.2 for examples).
A default layout is currently computed as a binary tree of alphabetically sorted field names.

To see the computed layout, you can look at the `Types` tab that shows the types including their layouts.